# Best, Cheap strategy to kill Queen Black Dragon

Tags: runescape

So in Runescape (EOC) I have attempted maybe 3 times to kill the QBD and I have absolutely no cash to spend on "the right" gear, as specified by the wiki. I just spend the last of my cash on a royal crossbow and I would like to bind it or forge it, however I am struggling to make it to the 4th wave.

My main problem is running out of food. I run out of sharks, and then have to attempt to take some from my war tortoise, but I cant simply due to the fact that I just keep getting hit. I then attempt to get it out as the wave ends, and 50 billion grotworms get thrown out, and then I get absolutely hammered by the fire walls.

My current setup is as follows:
Skills:
88 magic, 90 constitution, 71 prayer, combat level: 180
Items:

- Full Ganodermic (including polypore)
- 6 super restore potions
- 2 anti fires (don't have 85 herblore for super antifire)
- royal crossbow (unforged)
- and the rest is food, with my BOB filled with sharks aswell

I currently have about 100k, and I absolutely suck at making money. I have full Dharoks in my bank, and 2 rune crossbows and full royal dragon hide armor. I am willing to make money, it's just that I would like to know what the cheapest, affective set would be?
Alternatively what are some good money making methods (currently) that will allow me to get the best gear possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Phase one**:
The Queen Black Dragon is fought in four phases. During the first phase, she will attack with melee (if you are within her attack range), Ranged, and Dragonfire. Be aware that this dragonfire attack can hit 700 or higher, so the use of antifire or super antifire potions are a necessity. She will also use a special fire wall attack (shown in the chat box with an orange message). You must pass through the gap in the flames to avoid damage. If this attack does hit, it will hit in the low 200s, dealing damage twice if it passes over you. Running through it may deal damage once, or, timed luckily, may not deal damage at all. In future phases, with multiple waves of flame, reaching a faraway gap may be difficult and running directly through the flames may be a better alternative to taking many hits upon failing to reach the gap. When the health bar for the first stage reaches zero, the Queen will start coughing up level 105 giant grotworms. Touch the dragonkin artefact in the centre of the platform to stop these from appearing. These can hit fairly hard with magic, so it is advised to dispatch them quickly. Avoid letting too many Grotworms spawn by activating the artefact as quickly as possible after depleting the Queen's health bar.

**Phase two**:
During the second phase, the Queen will summon a level 137 tortured soul to attack. They will use an avoidable attack that hits about 1000 every time, and then attack with melee. Kill the tortured souls, and then attack the Queen. During this phase, the fire wall special attack will cause two consecutive walls of fire to appear, instead of just one. When the Queen's lifebar runs out, she will cough up more worms. A quick player can touch the second artefact, which is on the left side of the chamber, while only allowing about two giant worms to spawn.
It is possible, when tortured souls have been spawned, to run through them and make them hurt themselves. To do this, remember that they will always teleport right before doing their special attack, at this time you should run through them, and the special attack will hit the tortured soul and not you. This takes some practice, but does save you a lot of time, because in the fourth wave it is possible to use the souls' special attacks to kill one of the four spawned souls in one hit.

**Phase three**:
The third phase is similar to the second. However, the Queen will summon two tortured souls instead of one, and there will be three fire waves, instead of two. Once her lifebar reaches zero for the third time, touch the artefact on the right side as quickly as possible.

**Phase four**:
The fourth phase is by far the most dangerous. She will summon four tortured souls at once to begin the wave. 4 of them will spawn around you and failing to move out of the way results in you being damaged at least 4000 which is the most common reason for death throughout the whole fight. Also, she will have a few new moves up her sleeve, such as a stronger fire breath and Time Stop. When attempting this phase, move the camera screen as if you are the Queen Black Dragon. Most players are generally busy fighting her they do not notice a soul teleport to one of the corners and therefore die because of this reason. When you are finished taking her health to 0, watch out for any moves if she does use them. She will still summon souls and potentially use her super dragonbreath before she coughs up worms.

-

*This comes from the runscape wiki and there is much more to be found on killing queen black dragon in here:* http://runescape.wiki/w/Queen_Black_Dragon/Strategies

Answer (score 2):

Your problem with getting your sharks out is, that your getting hit when you try take the food out so then you cant take it out but what you do is right click on summoning bar on combat bar then you should see something called take from pet click this then you can take out of your pet while getting attacked. hope that helps you a bit.